# Como puedo hacer que grafique solo si la cantidad de casos es mayor a 2?

Tags: r, condiciones, shiny

Tengo un grafico de barras en SHINY R  que grafica según seleccione un perfil de tres posibles (cada perfil esta en una columna especifica y contiene el nombre de determinada persona "FullnameI", "FullnameD","FullnameA",
), el tiempo que le tomo a cada persona hacer determinado proceso(tenemos dos tipos de procesos que son:"operatingRoomList.recambio.elapsedTime" y "times.simpleMinutesRoomOccupancyTime", ademas un rango de fechas en las que me puedo mover,  quiero que grafique solo a las personas que hicieron 2 veces o más el proceso.
Todo esto teniendo en cuenta que el perfil puede cambiar así como el tipo de proceso.

ui

```
    tabsetPanel(position= "left",
     tabPanel("Indicadores 2", icon = icon("user-clock"),
     sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
        uiOutput("Selectproce"),
        uiOutput("SelectProfesional"),
        uiOutput("SelectTiempo"),
        uiOutput("RandeDated")
     ),
     mainPanel(
        plotOutput("lineplotTS"),
        dataTableOutput("summary6"),
        dataTableOutput("summary7")
     )
```

server

```
    output$Selectproce<-renderUI({
    selectInput("Selectproce", "Seleccione Procedimiento",
          BDnuevo$procedureCodes.0.name, multiple = F, selected = TRUE) 
    })
    BD6.2<-reactive({
    BDnuevo %>%
    filter(procedureCodes.0.name %in% input$Selectproce)
    })

    output$SelectProfesional<-renderUI({
    selectInput("SelectProfesional", "Seleccione perfil", choices = c("Instrumentadores"="FullnameI" 
    ,
                                                                "Cirujano"="FullnameD",
                                                                "Anestesiologo"="FullnameA")
    ) 
    })
    output$SelectTiempo <-renderUI({
    selectInput("SelectTiempo", "Seleccione indicador", 
          choices = c( "Tiempo de recambio" = "operatingRoomList.recambio.elapsedTime",
                       "Tiempo de sala"="times.simpleMinutesRoomOccupancyTime")) 
    })


    Fechasd<-reactive({
    BD6.3<-BD6.2()
    unique(BD6.3$simpleOriginDate)
    })
    output$RandeDated<-renderUI({
    dateRangeInput('dateRange6',
             label = 'Seleccione un rango',
             start = min(Fechasd(),na.rm=T), max(Fechasd(),na.rm=T)
    )
    })

    BD6.4<-reactive({
    BD6.5<-BD6.2()
    BD6.5 %>%
    filter(simpleOriginDate >= input$dateRange6[1] & simpleOriginDate <= input$dateRange6[2]) %>%
    group_by_at(input$SelectProfesional) %>%
    summarise_at(input$SelectTiempo,median,na.rm=T)

     })

    output$lineplotTS <- renderPlot({
    BD6.5<-BD6.4()
    ggplot(BD6.5, aes(x=reorder(.data[[input$SelectProfesional]],.data[[input$SelectTiempo]]), 
    y=.data[[input$SelectTiempo]]))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity",fill = "slateblue4")+
    coord_flip()+
    theme_bw()+
    labs(x ="Nombre", y ="Mediana")
    })
    BD6.7<-reactive({
    BD6.8<-BD6.2()
    subset (BD6.8,BD6.8$operatingRoomList.recambio.elapsedTime >=1 & 
    BD6.8$operatingRoomList.recambio.elapsedTime <= 120)%>% 
    filter(simpleOriginDate >= input$dateRange6[1] & simpleOriginDate <= input$dateRange6[2]) %>%
    group_by_at(input$SelectProfesional) %>%
    summarise(across(input$SelectTiempo,list(min,median,max,IQR),na.rm=T))
    })

    output$summary6<-DT::renderDataTable({
    BD6.8<-BD6.7()
    datatable(BD6.8, colnames = c("Nombre","Minimo","Mediana","Maximo","RQ"), class = 'cell-border 
    stripe', options = list(
    order = list(list(3, 'desc'))))

    })

    output$summary7<-DT::renderDataTable({
    BD6.8<-BD6.2()
    BD6.8 %>%
    BD6.8$operatingRoomList.recambio.elapsedTime <= 120)%>% 
    group_by_at(input$SelectProfesional)%>%
    count(sort = TRUE)
    })
    })
```

Ejemplo de base de datos

```
    BDnuevo<-data.frame("procedureCodes.0.name"<- 
    as.factor(c("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","fff","aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","fff","aaa","bbb", 
    "ccc","ddd","aaa","aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd")),
    "FullnameI"<-as.factor(c("Erika Castañeda","Pepito Perez","Andres Gonzalez","Jose 
     Rodriguez","Pepito Perez","Erika Castañeda","Pepito Perez","Andres Gonzalez","Jose 
     Rodriguez","Andres Gonzalez", "Jose Rodriguez","Jose Rodriguez","Andres Gonzalez","Jose 
     Rodriguez","Erika Castañeda","Pepito Perez","Pepito Perez","Pepito Perez","Andres Gonzalez")),
    "FullnameD"<-as.factor(c("Tata Guavita","Omar Garcia","Angel Ruiz","Natalia Rios","Tata 
     Guavita","Omar Garcia","Angel Ruiz","Natalia Rios","Tata Guavita","Tata Guavita","Omar 
     Garcia","Tata Guavita","Natalia Rios","Tata Guavita","Tata Guavita","Omar Garcia","Tata 
     Guavita","Natalia Rios","Tata Guavita")),
    "FullnameA"<-as.factor(c("Camila Arboleda","Yenny Jimenez","Augusto Arevalo","Daniel 
     Castaño","Camila Arboleda","Yenny Jimenez","Augusto Arevalo","Daniel Castaño","Camila 
     Arboleda","Yenny Jimenez","Augusto Arevalo","Camila Arboleda","Yenny Jimenez","Camila 
     Arboleda","Yenny Jimenez","Camila Arboleda","Yenny Jimenez","Augusto Arevalo","Daniel 
     Castaño")),
    "operatingRoomList.recambio.elapsedTime"<-c(23,13,14,15,25,13,34,23,43,12,23,12,45,    
     32,31,34,31,23,17),
    "times.simpleMinutesRoomOccupancyTime"<-c(23,24,14,15,13,18,16,15,14,17,18,19,11,21,14, 
     15,13,16,17),
    "simpleOriginDate"<-c(17/03/2012,14/04/2019,16/06/2021,13/08/2019,14/07/2021,13/02/2018,
     12/11/2018,13/10/2016,12/04/2018,14/06/2017,17/08/2021,7/09/2018,8/12/2017,9/11/2019,23/12/2017,
     11/02/2020,12/09/2015,13/09/2017,15/05/2021))
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que pusiste sólo lo mínimo necesario para reproducir tu problema? Quiero ayudar pero veo muchas cosas que no corresponden

Comment: Oye gracias, es que queria estar segura de que me entendieran, que tal así:      
          BD6.5 %>%
          group_by_at(input$SelectProfesional) %>%
          summarise_at(input$SelectTiempo,median,na.rm=T)                                       despues de que agrupa que cuente cuales tienen mas de 20 datos y a esos les calcule la media